# Android App Crashing Log in using sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, authentication, runtime-error

I'm building a simple login app, i have written a simple sqlite for adding user and for checking user for log in. once i add a user i get a null pointer error and my app crashes below is code. the null pointer is found when adding the users using the add method at the register class below

Regsiter class the crash happens here.

```
private Button register;
private EditText names;
private EditText username;
private  EditText password;
private DatabaseHelper db;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
    register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.regis);
    names = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    username =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.user);
    password =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);


    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        String n = names.getText().toString();
        String u = username.getText().toString();
        String p = password.getText().toString();
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            db.addUser(new User(n,u,p));
        }
    });


}
```

DatabseClass

```
 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.content.Context;
  import android.database.Cursor;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;


  public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "User.db";


private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";


private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_USERNAME = "user_username";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";


private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
        + COLUMN_USER_USERNAME + " varchar(50) primary key not null,"
        + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";




public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    //Drop User Table if exist
    db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

  }

public void addUser(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_USERNAME, user.getUsername());
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_USER, null, values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_ABORT);
    db.close();
}


public boolean checkUser(String username,String password){
    // array of columns to fetch
    String[] columns = {
            TABLE_USER
    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    // selection criteria
    String selection = COLUMN_USER_USERNAME + " = ?" + " AND " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " = ?";

    // selection arguments
    String[] selectionArgs = {username, password};

    // query user table with conditions
    /**
     * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
     * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
     * SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_email = 'jack@androidtutorialshub.com' AND user_password = 'qwerty';
     */
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, //Table to query
            columns,                    //columns to return
            selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
            selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                       //group the rows
            null,                       //filter by row groups
            null);                      //The sort order

    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    if (cursorCount > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try adding 'db = new DatabaseHelper(this);' in the onCreate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your DatabaseHelper variable db in on create method like 
               db= new DatabaseaHelper(this)

Comment: hello it worked but im getting issues with log in Process: com.example.alijammal.mapproject, PID: 4569
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.example.alijammal.mapproject.DatabaseHelper.checkUser(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.alijammal.mapproject.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)

Comment: String username = user.getText().toString().trim();
 String password = pass.getText().toString().trim();


       boolean checker= db.checkUser(username,password);


          if(checker){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);}